# Retrieve any unknown matrix A given $B = AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that if C is an orthonormal matrix, $$(AC)(AC)^T = AA^T$$. I know that A is not entirely unique, but is unique up to translations, rotations, and reflections. I am looking for an algorithm to recover any such A (which would define the entire class of satisfying matrices). I'm not sure how I can do that though.

Comment: You have a unique square root which is symmetric definite positive (and if it is not invertible you can still choose one). The step are diagonalize, then you have $AA^T = PDP^{-1}$ where $D = \operatorname {diag} (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$, then just take $A':= P \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\dots,\sqrt{\lambda_n}) P^{-1}$. Check polar decomposition for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B=AA^T$ is symmetric. Therefore, it has an eigendecomposition $B=V\Lambda V^T$. Moreover, the eigenvalues are non-negative, so you can write $\Lambda =\sqrt{\Lambda}\sqrt{\Lambda}^T$. Now, you have

$$B=(V\sqrt{\Lambda}) (V\sqrt{\Lambda})^T$$

---

Edit: To prove that the eigenvalues are non-negative. Take a an eigenvector $v$ of $B$. Then, $Bv=\lambda v$, then
$$v^T Bv=\lambda \Vert v\Vert^2$$
$$v^T A^T Av=\lambda \Vert v\Vert^2$$
Now, rewrite the LHS as a norm
$$\frac{\Vert Av \Vert^2}{\Vert v\Vert^2} = \lambda $$
Clearly, $\lambda \ge 0$.  Note: If $A$ is invertible, then all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: How do you know that the eigenvalues are non-negative

Comment: I have edited my answer, see above.